# How to make multiple API requests to fetch page data with NextJS - getServerSideProps?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, getserversideprops

I'm seeing an issue with fetching page data which comprises of 12+ components, each having a separate API endpoint to fetch the data from.

I was using this approach earlier but page performance seems to be taking a hit when making 12 requests like this -

```
    const [getHeaderRes, getFooterRes] = await Promise.allSettled([
      getHeader(),
      getFooter(),
    ])
```

Do we continue to make requests like this or there is a better way ?

**Maybe take API requests to component itself with good old useEffect ? But doesn't that nullifies the benefits of SSR ?**

Comment: You've discovered the trade-off of SSR - lots or pre-render work? no way to let user know other than a spinner in the layout component. Alternative, as you recognize, is to show the page skeleton and render components as they have data available. Think of this as a very large image that you must wait to download completely before rendering, vs. a progressively loaded image that shows up gradually over time. Which UX do you want to provide to your end user.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Thanks for the response.

I wish to have the content being served from the server for web crawlers to access it. I guess the page load time has to take the hit then right ?

Comment: yes - if SEO is the driving concern, SSR is the best solution.